# Expansion of solid spherical body when charged with a charge Q

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law, dielectric

Consider a solid sphere with no initial charge, now we supply a charge Q to it uniformly throughout the volume.
As per our expectations, the sphere must expand(if not forced by any external source). I wish to ask on what all factors will this expansion depends?
Had we been given with the values of required parameters, how can we calculate the expanded radius of the sphere?

Comment: The expansion would not be much significant

Comment: But why?? There is significant amount of force in radial direction in each case and there is nothing stopping them as such.

Comment: Use symmetry arguments as the charge distribution is symmetrical so most of the forces would cancel out